# minimal audio player using Flex and ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I am trying to build an audio player using FLEX and ActionScript 3 development.
I am building in Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 on Windows 7.

It is a simple audio player that loads a MP3 file from local disk and plays it.

Here's the code that I wrote:

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
mySound.load(new URLRequest("sANDm.mp3")); // load local MP3 file
mySound.play();
```

But the above code does not work. When I load the page in HTML document.

However If I create same code in Flash Professional then it works.

I have checked that MP3 file ("sANDm.mp3") exists in the directory where my HTML document and SWF file are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing debug version of Flash player and looking at debugger output messages I found what I was doing wrong.

Here's the correct code to build a minimal audio player:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class music_player extends Sprite
    {
        public function music_player()
        {
            var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
            mySound.load(new URLRequest("sANDm.mp3"));
            mySound.play();

        }
    }
}
```